# Elasticsearch sort terms agg by arbitrary order

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a terms aggregation and they want some specific values to always be at the top.

Like:

```
POST _search
{  "size": 0,

   "aggs": {
     "pets": {
       "terms": {
         "field": "species",
         "order": "Dogs, Cats"
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Where the results would be like "Dog", "Cat", "Iguana".
Dog and Cat at the top and everything else below.

Is this possible without scripting?

Thanks!

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A script wouldn't be too complicated though -- first boost the two species, then sort by the scores first and then by `_count`:

```
GET pets/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "species": [
              "dog",
              "cat"
            ],
            "boost": 10
          }
        },
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "pets": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "species.keyword",
        "order": [
          {
            "max_score": "desc"
          },
          {
            "_count": "desc"
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_score": {
          "max": {
            "script": "_score"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You may need to change `"field": "species.keyword"` to `"field": "species"` depending on your mapping.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is by [filtering values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_exact_values_2) in the `terms` aggregation. You'd create two terms aggregations, one with the desired terms and another with all other terms.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "top_terms": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "species",
        "include": ["Dogs", "Cats"],
        "order": { "_key" : "desc" }
      }
    },
    "other_terms": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "species",
        "exclude": ["Dogs", "Cats"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Try it out

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, only problem is that if Cats has more doc hits, it will still come first. Couldn't figure out a way to "Make Dogs first no matter how many hits".

Comment: Of course, you can change the order of the terms to make Dogs appear before Cats (by specifying in which `order` the buckets must be ordered), see my updated answer